# I want to create a slide that goes behind other images

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I know im stupid about this, but i cant simply figure out what is called or how to best approach this.

I want to create a slider that has one focus image in the middle and other images extrudes out in the sides. like presented in the image here
[image]

And of course when you click left or right it should go in that direction.

My approach so far is to make inline-flex and then make 5 divs where in each are an image and the center one is larger etc. and so on outwards.

But im still curious on how to make this work the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared an example that should meet all your conditions: swiping, scaling, prev/next buttons, click on card

```js
const gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery')
const cardWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.card-wrapper')
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev-button')
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button')

let selectedIndex = 2

// move card position depend on selected index

const applyCardPositions = () => {
  cardWrappers.forEach((cardWrapper, index) => {
    const workingIndex = selectedIndex <= 2
        ? index + (2 - selectedIndex)
      : index - selectedIndex + 2
    cardWrapper.dataset.index = index
    cardWrapper.dataset.position = Math.abs(index - selectedIndex)
    cardWrapper.style.left = `${ workingIndex * 20 }%`
  })
}

applyCardPositions()

// helpers

const decreaseSelectedIndex = () => {
  if (selectedIndex > 0) {
    selectedIndex -= 1
        applyCardPositions()
  }
}

const increaseSelectedIndex = () => {
  if (selectedIndex < cardWrappers.length - 1) {
    selectedIndex += 1
        applyCardPositions()
  }
}

// button events

prevButton.addEventListener('click', decreaseSelectedIndex)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', increaseSelectedIndex)

// click on card

cardWrappers.forEach(cardWrapper => {
    cardWrapper.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    selectedIndex = parseInt(cardWrapper.dataset.index)
        applyCardPositions()
  })
})

// swipe events

startPos = [0, 0]
gallery.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => {
    startPos = [e.clientX, e.clientY]
})

gallery.addEventListener('pointerup', (e) => {
    const endPos = [e.clientX, e.clientY]
  
  // threshold
  if (Math.abs(endPos[0] - startPos[0]) < 50) {
    return
  }
  
  if (endPos[0] < startPos[0]) {
    increaseSelectedIndex()
  }
  
  if (endPos[0] > startPos[0]) {
    decreaseSelectedIndex()
  }
})
```

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  
.gallery .card-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
}
    
.gallery .card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 100%;;
  background: #ddd;
  user-select: none;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
}
      
.gallery [data-position="0"] .card {
  background: #aaa
}

.gallery [data-position="1"] .card {
  transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
}

.gallery [data-position="2"] .card {
  transform: scale3d(.8, .8, .8);
}

.gallery [data-position="3"] .card {
  transform: scale3d(.7, .7, .7);
}

.prev-button,
.next-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 10px;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
  user-select: none;
}

.next-button {
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">F</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="prev-button">
    &lt;
  </div>
  
  <div class="next-button">
    &gt;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whatever i apreciate everything, @Asobitu Do you know for the best fact to loop it ?

Comment: @Melonendk Do you mean if you go to the left at the first one, you start again at the last one and vice versa? Maybe something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qdhjubnf/

Comment: @Melonendk Sorry, in this case we also need to fix the CSS a little bit, because all the cards outside the view are not scaled and it looks a little bit weird. Here's an updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/qdhjubnf/1/